# Detect this FPGA board, where to find Schemantics?

Tags: fpga

Google image search returns birds and balls with this image but, as far as I see, it has nothing to do with them.

[image]

Google image search returns clothes, cotton and some odd small people with this but, as far as I can see, it has nothing to do with them.

[image]

I bought the board from Chinese site `"www.21eda.com"` but it is now closed. I have tried to find information in Chinese, more [here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/845/technical-vocabulary-for-%E9%9B%BB%E8%B7%AF%E5%9C%96-to-find-technical-pdf-documents), but I am unable to spot the right specs, I had them so I have some sense what they look like. How can I find schemantics (showing the logic/IOs/etc in the board)?

**Specs**

1. Cyclone II EP2C5T144C8N K BBD9Y0931A
2. Some chip: AM29LV160DB - 90EF 0929FBA D 1998 AMD
3. Some chip: Hynix 002F A HY57V641620FTP-6 KOR
4. Board ID: SN:21EDA0811577 (at the back of the board like [here](https://plus.google.com/photos/118074578707201714689/albums/5584609220750787361?banner=pwa))
5. Probably the board [here](https://plus.google.com/photos/118074578707201714689/albums/5584617466125047665?banner=pwa), now have to find the schematics/getting-started material.

Comment: AM29LV160DB = AMD 16 Megabit (2M x 8-Bit/1M x 16-Bit)
CMOS 3.0 Volt-only Boot Sector Flash Memory ... HY57V641620F = Hynix 64Mb Synchronous DRAM based on 1M x 4Bank x16 I/O

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's this one: http://www.aliexpress.com/store/801899/210558845-449776833/Free-shipping-FPGA-21EDA-EP2C5T144-development-board-FPGA-learning-board-NIOS-dev-board.html

[image]

I'm guessing it's an evaluation board for an Altera CycloneII FPGA with Nios II Processor.

Comment: You probably mean the Altera Cyclone II with a NIOS soft core (check the FPGA label).

Comment: Ah yes - the product description says CycloneII