# Do I need to buy USB Blaster with DE0-Nano?

Tags: fpga, jtag, intel-fpga

I am moving this question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/18865/2387) to separate question altogether:

> [DE0-Nano] [l]ooks really good, but do I need to buy the USB Blaster (or another
>   programmer) too?

Please, explain the context in a beginner style, what is it really needed for?

**Related things**

1. http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&No=46#section (USB Blaster clone)
2. http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?No=593 (DE0-Nano board)

Comment: ...50USD S&H, any idea how to order this board with less shipping cost? I need to arrange my own courier. Like is there any sense to order many of them -- 50USD S&H is a way too much when  the board costs 50USD itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says clearly on the website:

> The advantages of the DE0-Nano board include its size and weight, as
>   well as its ability to be reconfigured without carrying superfluous
>   hardware <...>

and

> **Configuration Status and Set-Up Elements**
>
> - On-board USB-Blaster circuit for programming
> - Altera serial configuration device – EPCS16

So no, you don't need an external programmer for this board.